# Where should flash files be stored in 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails 3.0.X, I would store my flash files in public/flash. Flash files such as: jwplayer, uploadify, etc.

With the introduction of the new directory structure in 3.1 (i.e. app/assets/), should flash files still be stored in public/flash or should I create a new directory called 'flash' in app/assets/ ?

Comment: I haven't started playing with 3.1, but I would be shocked if anything in app/assets can be served publicly - that wouldn't make sense from either a security viewpoint or from honoring the convention of the public directory. Since you need these flash files to be publicly accessible, you should store them in public.

Comment: Based on that understanding. What about the app images? If images such as logo, banner, main background, icons are considered public, why is there an images directory in app/assets? Or should we still put these types of images in public/images. If so, what is the images dir in app/assets used for?

Comment: @JeremyWeathers: The asset pipeline is for hiding private content. It's for precompiling assets and cache busting.

Comment: I wanted to write: The asset pipeline is NOT for hiding private content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if these are `.swf` files, I don't think they belong in `app/assets`. The asset folder allows for pre-"compiled" app asset files for CoffeeScript and SCSS (or similar js and css "compilers"). If you are compiling `.as` files into `.swf` files as part of your deploy or startup process, I could see it making sense to put them in the asset folder. However, this seems like a horrible idea.

=================UPDATE=====================

I was wrong. The asset folder is for serving Sprockets assets. As long as you can handle digested asset paths you should use Sprockets.

Comment: If they are meant for pre-"compiled" app asset files, why is there an images dir in app/assets there?

Comment: Christian, we have images in our app that are only included in app-generated PDFs. It makes sense to store these in app/assets rather than public.

Comment: I disagree. It's not just for precompiled assets. If you use the Rails asset pipeline, you will benefit from it's cache busting feature and tell the browser to cache them forever. Thats why images have also a place in the assets. But you cannot use hard coded paths. If you take care of that (e.g. tell the flash all paths via rails generated flash vars or xmls), you can benefit of this a lot.

Comment: I actually have to agree with iGEL. Having now used Sprockets for a longer period I would say that if you can handle "digested" paths, you should put your swf files in the assets directory..

Answer (score 12):

You can use the [Sprockets `provide` directive](http://getsprockets.org/installation_and_usage#bundling_assets_with_the_provide_directive).

For example, this is how I am using Plupload:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/plupload.js
//= require plupload/plupload
//= require plupload/plupload.flash
//= require plupload/plupload.silverlight
//= provide plupload/dependencies
```

The corresponding vendor directory is organised like this:

```
vendor
├── assets
│   ├── javascripts
│   │   └── plupload
│   │       ├── dependencies
│   │       │   ├── plupload.flash.swf
│   │       │   └── plupload.silverlight.xap
│   │       ├── plupload.flash.js
│   │       ├── plupload.js
│   │       └── plupload.silverlight.js
│   └── stylesheets
└── plugins
```

I then use `<%= javascript_include_tag 'plupload' %>` when I want to use Plupload, and use the `asset_path` helper to populate the Plupload configuration:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'plupload' %>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
        runtimes : 'flash,silverlight',
        multipart : true,
        multipart_params : {
            'authenticity_token' : '<%= form_authenticity_token %>'
        },
        flash_swf_url : 
            '<%= asset_path "plupload/dependencies/plupload.flash.swf" %>',
        silverlight_xap_url :
            '<%= asset_path "plupload/dependencies/plupload.silverlight.xap" %>',
        url : '<%= url_for [@item, :photos] %>',
        // ...
    });
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think, there are good arguments for both places. Using the asset pipeline (store them under /app/assets) has the disadvantage, that cannot hard link any static files from the flash, since you cannot tell the filename in production (Rails will add a hash sum of the content to the file name). You will have to generate flashvars or xml files with Rails containing the resource filenames.

However, if you use the asset pipeline, each file will get a new hash sum in its file name, if the file changes. You can tell the browser to cache the files forever, because once you reference a changed file, it will be new to the browser (<- file name) and it will load the changed file from the server. Caching will make your site faster for returning visitors.